# How to declare and initialise multidimensional array with NULLs

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char *number_groups[2][4][2] = {
        {
            {"5", "6"},
            {"5.0", "6.0"},
            {"5/1", "6/1"},
            {"15/3", "-12/-2"},
        },
        { // number_groups[1]
            {"-98765432109876543210", "98765432109876543210"},
            {"-98765432109876543210.0", "98765432109876543210"},
            {"-98765432109876543210/1", "98765432109876543210/1"},
            NULL // number_groups[1][3]
        }
    };
    printf("(number_groups[1][3] == NULL) == %d\n", number_groups[1][3] == NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

([test the code](http://ideone.com/kX2ZGQ))

**I want to create a multidimensional array, elements of which are pairs for c-strings.**

If I was making just an array of 10 c-strings, I could fill it with 2 c-strings and other 8 pointers would be `NULL`s, but if I want to make a more sophisticated array like what I posted at the top of this post, I don't know how to do that.
Here is an example of the difference between initializing an array of 10 c-strings and an array of 10 arrays:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char* array[10] = { "/usr/bin/ls", "-l" };
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        printf("(array[%d] == NULL) == %d\n", i, array[i] == NULL);
    }

    const char* array2[10][2] = {
        {"aa", "bb"},
        {"bb", "cc"}
    };
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        printf("(array2[%d] == NULL) == %d\n", i, array2[i] == NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

([test the code](http://ideone.com/RRS7Ak))

Comment: The array does contain NULL pointers. But you're not testing the values off the stored pointers, you're testing the addresses of the sub-arrays. And clearly, those cannot be NULL. Test the values of the actual pointers (by using 2 subscripts, instead of one). http://ideone.com/AknP5q

Comment: You should, like, totally use `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h`. It's what all the cool kids are doing these days.

Comment: What you're suggesting to do is to use NULL pointers instead of pointers to char.

Comment: Who's suggesting what? I'm not suggesting that. That suggestion doesn't even make any sense. "pointers to char" is a type, "NULL pointer" is a value. What I'm suggesting is that instead of checking if `array2[i] == NULL`, you check if `array2[i][0] == NULL` or `array2[i][1] == NULL`. See the link I provided in my previous comment.

Comment: Well, I want to have a way to show that an array has ended, there are no more elements in it. I wanted to use a NULL pointer showing that, but looks like it's not possible in this case. So what you're suggesting is to have my [10][2] array fully initialised, with space allocated for all 20 elements, but when I want to show, that there are not 10 elements in the 0-th dimension, but only 2, all other 16 elements should be zero. 1. That's less memory-savvy 2. What if I actually wanted to use NULL pointers as legitimate elements?

Comment: Actually, I wasn't making any suggestion about how you *should* initialize your array. I was just telling you that you *did* initialize your array, and that you initialized with a bunch of NULL pointers.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that now. But how do I initialise it properly, the way I want?

Comment: @CrabMan: Do you want C++, or C?  And Chnossos, please don't remove the C++ tag from questions which contain valid C++ without getting clarification from the OP about what language he's actually interested in.

Comment: C++ without use of C++ standard library or STL.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley At the time I edited there weren't any comment, since both tags were specified I guessed from the includes aaaaand I was wrong.

Comment: @Chnossos: Well, don't guess. Ask. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158450/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thank you for the review and link !

Comment: You'll have to choose a different data structure. My suggestion would be to use `std::vector` from the standard library. But since you've limited yourself from that option, I would then suggest you implement a class that just so happens to have very similar functionality to `std::vector`, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

C-style arrays are a little confusing and archaic. They are just a shorthand for mapping axes onto a block of data.

In this example you can see that there are (at least) 4 ways of accessing the same element in a c-style array:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define X_EXTENT 4

const char* array2[10][X_EXTENT];

int main() 
{
    int y = 5, x = 1;

    array2[y][x] = "hello";
    cout << array2[y][x] << endl;

    cout << *(array2[y] + x) << endl;

    cout << *(*(array2 + y ) + x) << endl;

    cout << *(reinterpret_cast<const char**>(array2) + y * X_EXTENT + x) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```